# Email Validation Format VB/Enabled button

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, drop-down-menu

Good Morning all :)
I am struggling with very basic I know but I have been debugging it all night, it works partially so please help.. I am trying to do some simple validation.. Email validation in format of abc@domain .com, I figured that one out the problem is it will show messege etc but it will proceed to the next form ( I have two forms) I want it to not proceed and ask user to change email input in order to proceed..

```
Protected Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 

    TextBox3.TextChanged
    Dim chk As String = TextBox3.Text

    If chk.Contains("@") And chk.Contains(".") Then

    Else

        MsgBox("This is not a valid email. Please re-enter your email.")
    End If
End Sub
```

The second question i have a drop down list i and underneath a textbox, I want to enable the text box only if I chosen "Sport & Dance" from the dropdownlist otherwise I want to diable it, this one though it sounds easy and logical but its not working for me, my code is below.. all help is much much appreciated

```
        Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged

    If DropDownList1.Text.Contains("Sport & Dance") Then

        TextBox2.Enabled = False
    Else

        TextBox2.Enabled = True

    End If
End Sub





      Protected Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged
    Dim chk As String = TextBox3.Text
    If chk.IndexOf("@", System.StringComparison.Ordinal) < 0 Then
        MsgBox("This is not a valid email. Please re-enter your email.")
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged

    If DropDownList1.SelectedValue = ("Sports & Dance") Then

        TextBox2.Enabled = False
    Else

        TextBox2.Enabled = True

    End If
```

Comment: For you'r seccond question U can check like this as  `if DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "Sport&Dance" `Then

Answer (score 1):

For the validation of email address..

```
   If chk.IndexOf("@", System.StringComparison.Ordinal) < 0 Then
       MsgBox("This is not a valid email. Please re-enter your email.")
   End If
```

For your dropdown,

```
    If DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "Sport & Dance" Then

        TextBox2.Enabled = False
    Else

        TextBox2.Enabled = True

    End If
```

Comment: Please check the Edited code.. I did exactly what you said and both are outpting my original outputs

Comment: you don't need to put my answer on your question. what's exactly your error? @Jane

Comment: No Error, it just after validating it is still proceeding to the next form... and the drop menu list.. if i make the selection the other text is not disabled

Comment: @Jane Then your email is valid if that's the case. While your drop down, please check exactly what's the `*value*` of the dropwdonwn, not the *item*

Comment: the email, it will display the Error messege then continue to Next form anyways and thats not right, it should stay on form until user makes the appropriate, The dropdownlist the Items name and Value is same in my code!

Comment: @Jane what's exactly the email you're validating??

Comment: my validation is as long it has @.. If it is in the Correct format, it will work find and move to next form. If it is not correct format , It will show the Error messege but the only problem it will move to next form.. I want to stay in page until User enter correct format